# Comma separated list

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How I can get comma separated name list like Abc, Xyz. Here is my code

```
<td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td><% user.user_policies.each{|user_policy| %>
          <%=user_policy.policy.name %>
    <%}%> </td>
   <td>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
policy_names = user.user_policies.map {|up| up.policy.name }
policy_name_list = policy_names.join(',')
```